# Noop method to avoid c# compiler optimize away a temp variable

Tags: c#, optimization

in a derivative calculation context I need to make sure x and x+h differ by an exactly representable number, so I have done this:

```
var temp = x + deltaX;
DoNothing(temp);
deltaX = temp - x;
```

DoNothing() method being there in order to prevent temp to be optimized away.

Is that correct way of handling this?

Comment: Going to go out on a limb here and say 'No'. What are the types of `temp`, `x`, and `deltaX`?

Comment: *confused* What exactly are you trying to achieve here? It seems that you're trying to make sure that `x` and `x + y` differ by a number that is always exactly representable in floating point. In that case you're asking the impossible: `y` might be exactly representable, but that doesn't guarantee that the result of `x + y` is exactly representable. Perhaps you could share what behaviour you're trying to achieve so that a better solution might be proposed?

Comment: What is your definition of exactly representable value? I don't think the code you present does anything. If either `x` or `deltaX` are large enough compared to each other, the smaller one is gonna get lost. Also being exactly representable might be something different than differ in value. E.g. 0.1 decimal is not exactly representable in IEEE754 specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That compiler optimization you are worried about is invalid with .NET. It's known to be done in C++ with "fast math" compiler settings. .NET guarantees IEEE floating point behavior with the exception that excess precision is allowed (not a problem here). The optimization would be value-changing in general so it's forbidden.

If you want to clear compiler knowledge of a value I always use:

```
[MethodImplOptions(NoInlining)]
T F<T>(T x) { return x; }
```

This is not guaranteed to work but it does with all JITs that are in existence at the moment. The .NET JITs are so weak at optimizing that I doubt they will add the kind of data flow analysis that would make this trick stop working.

Comment: Thanks @usr, did I understand you correctly that the code I have written is fine? or did you mean I don't need DoNothing() call in between at all?

Comment: You don't need DoNothing. Even if it was present it would not necessarily do anything to prevent the optimization you are concerned about. I don't see why the function call would be an optimization barrier.